# Break span into different elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to break this span into two different ID's using jQuery:

```
<span id="foo">0.00 (0.00%)</span>
```

Outcome to look like:

```
<span id="foo1">0.00</span>
<span id="foo2">(0.00%)</span>
```

Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
// obtain text and break it at the space
var t = $('#foo').text().split(' ');

// rename 'foo' and set its content
$('#foo').attr('id', 'foo1').text(t[0]);

// create new element and put it after foo
$('<span>', {id: 'foo2', text: t[1]}).insertAfter('#foo1');
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the text contents into an array, create new nodes for each array element and then replace the current tag with the newly created elements:

```
$('#foo').replaceWith(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    return $.map($this.text().split(' '), function(o, i) {
        return $('<span>', {
            id: $this.prop('id') + (i + 1),
            text: o
        }).get(0);
    });
});
```

Granted, it might be a bit too generic for the actual question at hand :)

Comment: granted, it does indeed more work to get the generic solution, but why (for example) use two different DOM methods to get the text instead of `.text()`.  You could also have used `.map` instead of a `for (...) { push }` loop.

Comment: @Alnitak Reworked the answer with something less complicated and more jQuery'ish :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var $foo = $('#foo');
var v = $foo.text().split(' ');

$foo.after($('<span id="foo2"></span>').text(v[1]));
$foo.after($('<span id="foo1"></span>').text(v[0]));
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/ByFbK/3/

Comment: I always try _never_ to concatenate strings and HTML to avoid string escaping issues.  It's OK for the OP's input, but what it the text had an `<` in it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var orig = $('#foo').text().split(' '),str='';
$(orig).each(function (idx, elem) {
    str += '<span id="foo' + (idx + 1) + '">' + elem + '</span>';
});
$('#foo').replaceWith(str);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/58PjH/)**